# Piggyback off Motherboard Power Switch?

Tags: motherboard

I have a custom computer with a custom case that I would like to re-purpose the power switch on, but only when the computer is running.

I have a [Teensy board](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/index.html) (similar to Arduino) inside the case that handles button presses and communicates to the custom application I have via USB.  The problem is, the front panel only has 2 buttons, one is being used for the motherboard power switch, so I only have one available and I need 2.  I don't want to physically add a new button for aesthetic reasons.

At first, I looked into Windows APIs for detecting the power button pressed, but it looks like the only way to do this is with a custom driver, and that's a route I don't want to go down (and I don't have a signing key for an x64 driver anyway).

So what I want to do is be able to use the motherboard power switch (on the front panel) to power on the computer, or wake it from sleep, but when the computer is running, have my Teensy board detect the press.  I've already set in Windows to have the power button do nothing when it's pressed while Windows is running.  I just need to figure out how to connect the Teensy board to the power switch to detect this without screwing with the power switch operation when the computer is off and going to be turned on.

The Teensy input can be configured to be external (where it must have high +5V or low 0V all the time - floating inputs do not work), or configured to have an internal pull up so it is high when floating externally, and low when connected externally.  The Teensy runs off USB +5V power, and I have confirmed that the USB ground and the power switch ground are the same ground.

Alas, searching online, I've had trouble finding specifications for how the power switch works, or even if it is standard amongst different motherboards.  So my question is, is there a way I can hook up to the motherboard power switch pins to still power on the motherboard when it is off (and the Teensy is therefore also off - no power on USB while off), but detect the button press on the Teensy input while it is on?

Comment: It's usually just connected to the green wire on an ATX PSU - pulling it to ground == pressing the switch.

Comment: @pjc50 - it can't be directly connected. The button is momentary but the power supply wire must be held to ground as long as the computer is on.

Answer (score 1):

For PC's made after the introduction of the ATX, the power switch is a logical input to the motherboard--the same kind of input you want to apply to the Teensy.   The motherboard, in turn, outputs a separate logic signal to turn on the power supply.

In my experience, the *reset* switch is as good as standard, as it dates back to the original IBM PC (which didn't have the switch, but did have a connection on the motherboard for one).  This is not so for the *power* switch.  I have seen schemes where it pulls a signal up and neither side is grounded.  Since you have found one side of your switch is connected to ground, that makes your connection easy.  Simply attach a voltmeter to the two pins, and observe the voltage present there.  Verify that this voltage drops to zero when pressing the switch.  Your Teensy will see this on its input.   It doesn't matter how they implemented this.  If it's a floating input they will have a pull up resistor already there to make it work.  Your input is just watching the resultant voltage level.

Note that the power supply is turned on when the motherboard drops the #PS_ON signal to ground.  This is the infamous "green wire" on the ATX connector.  If you bring this signal into a second input on your Teensy, you will now be able to tell if the button was pushed while the computer is already running (because it will show a logic 0).

Also note that certain voltages are always present even when the computer is off (or in standby).  This is how the power switch manages to have power when there's no power.  This is also a heads up that you may find power in other unplanned places (like some USB connections).

Comment: This sounds promising.  I'll try to determine if the power switch is using the same logic as the Teensy, and the same voltage (5V).  The Teensy input triggers on the same reference voltage as its power (USB 5V).  This was my main concern - connecting the Teensy input to drain to the motherboard pins when instead of itself.  But if the motherboard has a pull up to the same 5V when open, and drains to the same ground when closed, then it sounds like it will work to connect the Teensy input (configured for external pull up) directly to the motherboard's input.

Comment: Also, thanks for the info on power switches being non-standard. This explains why I had trouble finding any standard online.  Fortunately, this is a one-off project.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, have your board control the computer power up. Connect the switch to your board directly. Then use an opto coupler or isolator from the board to the power switch connector on the computer motherboard. Finally, use one of the 5v switched power lines as an input to your board. When your board senses the 5v rail as off, pressing the switch causes it to activate the optó in turn turning on the pc. When the pc turns on, the 5v input turns on, and the microcontroller goes into your regular code.

If you need to power the microcontroller while the pc is off, use the 5v standby power rail. It is normally on regardless of the power to the rest of the power supply.

Comment: A small relay might be the only way to go.  Ideally, I would like all power switch functions to work - like holding the button down to force a power off. But I can just always trigger the relay when pressed, so no need to detect on/off.

The only issue might be the USB connection.  I don't think the base USB implementation provided with the Teensy supports just the data lines disconnecting while power remains on.  I'll have to see how hard this is to modify.  But if worse comes to worse, I could just include a second Teensy board to handle this and send signals to the other board.